# [React]Container Component design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 3 components in a html page.

**A,B,C**

By the PSD desgin ,in the `DOM` level , `A includes B and B includes C.`

so in the React level , I'd like to design component tree as follow:

```
A(stateful component) ->B (stateless component) ->C (stateless component)
```

I will make `A` **redux-aware** by `connect` method and hand down the redux state `to B then -> C`.

However many guides recommend that **a stateful component can only contain stateless components** whereas there's no mentioned whether:

**1. a stateless component can contain another stateless component?**

**2. a stateless component can contain another stateful component?**

**3. a stateful component can contain another stateful compoent?**

so anyway ,how to design my components, thanks in advance!!

```
A(stateful component) ->B (stateless component) ->C (stateless component)
```

**both B and C** expect the state from **A** to pass down to them.**

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eet4ez, it might help you

Comment: thanks , but this code sample seems to tell different story.

Answer (score 1):

Some times you can learn more my reading example code, take a look at this [example Todo List provided by redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/components/MainSection.js) it clearly shows that `MainSection` contains `TodoItem` and a `Footer` both of which are stateful and `MainSection` itself is stateful. A major example may even be the Material-UI library which is all stateful components and you can use it with stateless or stateful components.

There is no reason stateless components can't contain state-less components and there is no reason stateless components can't contain stateful components. An example of a stateless component containing stateful components is literally your top level `App` or `index` file at times. If the repo linked above, take a look at `App.js`.

The main concern with stateful components containing stateful components is a lot of needless updates to your UI. These are some times not obvious because the shadow DOM diff's against the DOM and makes the appropriate changes, but there is non-the-less a cost to the diff and the operation is triggered every time your state changes.

A good way to solve this issue is to keep your components fairly flat in their dept or to implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` function as needed.

Having state in your components just makes things easier to manage due to separation of concerns, so I find it hard to believe using them under stateful or stateless components could be an issue. Stateless components will render every time the component that contains them renders, so perhaps the issue of embedding stateless components inside stateless components is one of depth, i.e. the deeper your DOM the more complex the diff operations (purely guessing based on experience) so the guideline discourage this so that you can keep your tree as flat as possible.

Honestly, I don't see any of this being a problem as long as you use good coding practices and are aware of the consequences of your decisions.

Comment: Much apprecaited!! thanks so much for your detailed explanation that have enlightened me!