# React+Redux Container/Component: hung up on naming or missing something fundamental re. the relationship?

Tags: react-redux

I'm writing a React+Redux app and separating my Containers and Components such that all my "plain" Components consist of a single render function with styling.

That all makes sense, but I'm new to the ecosystem and want to build so other developers can follow my work; i.e., with good style and without introducing local idioms. The confusing thing is that all the examples and docs are written in terms of 'Components'. While understanding that a 'Container is a Component', I end up importing and using only the Containers everywhere.

As far as I understand the theory here, that isn't surprising, but in terms of style, it feels like I'm breaking (at least what I understand) as the conventions. Even the Redux+React with Container/Component specific sample code seems to uniformly only ever import seemingly "plain" Components.

What I really want to do is something like:
* Refer to and organize the primary entry point objects as 'components', so `import Foo from './components/Foo`.
* Qualify the dumb, render only Components with a qualifier like 'view', so `FooView`, `views/Foo`, or `components/views/Foo` or something.

But no one seems to do that. This makes me worry that maybe I'm actually misunderstanding something fundamental. Or am I reading too much into the exmaples I've seen so far?

As a most basic example, say we have Component `Foo`,

```
// src/components/Foo.js
import React from 'react';

const Foo = (props) =>
   <div>
    Hello {props.userName}!
  </div>

export default Foo
```

and associated Container `FooContainer`:

```
// src/containers/FooContainer.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Foo from '../components/Foo';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userName: state.sessionState.userName,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```

Then to kick it all off:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render } from 'react-dom';
import AppContainer from './containers/AppContainer'

render(
  <AppContainer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Question 1)** Most basically, am I missing something by now importing and using the Container-Components everywhere (as opposed to the 'Components')?

If that's how it's supposed to work, then the naming of everything seems to be off... I've seen some examples where the developers name the plain Containers and Component-Containers the same thing, and that's fine, but I still end up referring to the `./containers` code instead of `./components` and all the examples always seem to import Components exclusively from `./components` without any basename suffix (e.g. it's always `import Foo from './components/Foo`, even when they reference using the Container/Component pattern and in other places giving explicit examples of using the `Container` suffix or a `./containers` directory.

**Question 2)** So, if I'm not misunderstanding the basics here, how is it that all the examples always seem to `import Foo from ./components/Foo`? Is there a step they're not showing, or am I just too hung up on the idea that I should (as a matter of convention) import from `./components`?

Again, if I'm not off track so far, then what I'd really like to do is to refer to the Container-Components as the most basic Component and organize them under `components` with no suffix. E.g., `components/Foo` would be the Container-Component and then the plain stateless Component would be under a `views` directory or something, so `FooView` or `views/Foo` would be the dumb, render-only Component.

My thinking is that if the Container-Component is really the primary entry point that gets used 95% of the time, then that's the thing I want to call a "Component" rather and use the special discriminator for the thing I don't actually use as much.

But I've never seen an example of anything other than calling the plain, stateless Components 'Components' and the stateful, method-ful stuff 'Containers'.

Comment: Looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291571/reactcontainer-component-design it seems like another option that clears up a lot of my confusion is to not tie the container and component together at all, but let the Container (the `Data' Component) be an explicit wrapper around the presentational Component. The downside here is that I'm importing ~twice as many Components and nothing ends up being standalone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple months working on iterations of this, here's what I've settled on as my ideal naming convention:

1. The presentation components, which actually do the rendering get plain names. E.g., `UserDetail`, `UsersList`, `TodoDetail`, `TodoList`, etc. These are ideally "pure" components that receive all data via props, though they may have some internal state related to visual rendering (such as whether a rendered component is open or closed). They should be self contained and never initiate network calls or touch the redux state (and therefore need not "pure", though that's nice). Presentation components may compose other presentation components.
2. Data providing 'containers' are implemented via 'higher order components' (HOCs). E.g., a the user data would be provided via the `withUser` HOC which would retrieve the user and set the `user` property of `UserDetail`. These contain logic to make network calls, pull from the redux or their own own state, or map other context data to properties for use by contained Components.

Comment: I've been revising this somewhat since the introduction of hooks and am switching to a system using hooks and render-prop components for network/business logic + state, while still retaining generally pure "render components".